# ActivityManager#getRunningServices returning service which is manually stopped

Tags: android, service

```
activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

This method returns a list which includes service which is stopped manually.

Settings > Applications > Running services

Comment: how you know that it is stopped?

Comment: I can see it is not in running services [Settings -> Applications -> running services]

Comment: hmm click on the menu you can see one options show all running service. can you check it once?

Comment: Yes, stopped service is not there.. but it is in list of activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the approaches using onDestroy or onSometing events or Binders or static variables will not work reliably because as a developer you never know, when Android decides to kill you process or which of the mentioned callbacks are called or not. Please note the "killable" column in the lifecycle events table in Android documentation.

//use this code to check your service is running or not

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if ("com.example.MyService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446565/android-how-do-i-check-if-activity-is-running

Comment: that is what i did.. which is failing.. as  manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE) is returning service which is manually stopped...

Comment: is that your own service of system default service which you stopped.

Comment: can you send your apk so that I can check.

Comment: I observed that service is still running..
but it is not shown under running services in settings.... :-?

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3_r1/com/android/settings/applications/RunningState.java#143
I can see if started flag is false and clientLable is =0 it is not shown in list

if (!si.started && si.clientLabel == 0) {
                 continue;
}

Is any callback which called when service is stopped using settings app?

Comment: Fixed this by adding hack...
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/c5f91f45cfa3e1cc?pli=1

     if ( !serviceInfo.started && (serviceInfo.clientLabel == 0) )
     {
      controller.stopService(MYSERVICE);
      return;
     }

Comment: Do not call "service.service.getClassName()" if your users may have several flavors of your application installed, which have the same service or this will return true, although your service is not running, but from another flavor