# Android UI Thread

Tags: java, android

i am using threads to do few tasks. and after that i want to access the main thread via runOnUiThread(). but how to determine whether that ui thread still running or not?

Comment: you mean if its sleeping? the ui thread is the main thread that your application starts in.

Comment: no i need to know whether that activity is still running or not

Comment: i think if you will access through runOnUIThread,it will work anytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Two options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446565/android-how-do-i-check-if-activity-is-running) are there one use a static boolean  variable and see whether the activity is running or not, or you can check all the running tasks and determine whether your activity is running or not.

Comment: how do you use the second method , meaning get running tasks and check if the activity is running?

Answer (score 0):

The only instance when your UI thread is not running is when your main thread has spawned a thread which needs to communicate with the UI thread and the non-UI thread has not been killed  when the life of the context ends.

You must avoid a situation like this by `interrupt()`ing your threads in `onStop()` or `onDestory()` (whatever is appropriate).

After you've taken care of this, you can always safely assume that a `runOnUiThread()` call is appropriate.

Comment: thank you for your input. due to the nature of the task which i am performing inside the thread, i need to complete it safely ,instead of breaking in the middle.