# How to see that is Activity running or not?

Tags: android

I have a BroadCastReceiver that is listen for incoming short messages. In SmsReceiver I want to start an Activity to process the sms. In many situation the Activity is running while getting message and I don't want to start it again.

In fact I want to see that if that Activity is already running (visible or not killed yet) just take it to front and otherwise start it with new task.

Any idea?

Comment: to bring activity to foreground use flag like intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: how do I check if activity is running?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446565/android-how-do-i-check-if-activity-is-running)

Comment: When I use this flag, I got "android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?"

Answer (score 0):

I mixed some ideas from here and other places and finally solved the problem. I write the solution here for other people that may have similar situations:

In amy Activity:

```
static boolean isRunning = false;

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    isRunning = true;
}

public void onStop() {
    isRunning = false;
    super.onStop();
}

public static boolean isRuuning() {
    return isRunning;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    smsReceiver = new SmsReceiver();
    smsReceiver.setActivity(this);
    // ...
}
```

Inside my SmsReceiver:

```
static MyActivity myActivity;

public void setActivity(MyActivity MyActivity) {
    SmsReceiver.myActivity = myActivity;
}   

if( MyActivity.isRuuning() ) {
    SmsReceiver.myActivity.receiveNewMessage(smsBody);
} else {
    // Create an intent and start it
}
```

This works fine for me.