# Search through open apps contents ADB Android

Tags: android, adb

Is it possible to search through a currently open developer's app (ie not signed) via adb?

I can currently use `adb shell` to sniff around inside the phone. But I have no idea if I can look at the current app that is open in the phone.

**[edit]**

Just for some background information, in my app I check to see if a file exists or not, this way I can tell if the app is live or just in development. As when the app is built for live different files are added.

So I use this:

```
        $.ajax({
            url:'file:///assets/www/cordova.js',
            type:'HEAD',
            error: function(el)
            {
                c(el.readyState);
            },
            success: function()
            {
                c('//file exists');
            }
        });
```

This will check if the file exists or not, however recently the files used have changed and I can no longer find them.

Comment: i am sorry for asking , can you explain more what you are really trying

Comment: Added some more information :D

Comment: some times this link will help you `Discovering if Android activity is running` http://stackoverflow.com/a/13212634