# How to check activity has been destroyed or no more running

Tags: android, android-activity

I am working on an android app and have an activity. I have written a code in my activity that will start a new activity after getting response from server, this code is getting executed even after I press back button on my activity.

So, I want to check that if my current activity is not active anymore, then the code should not run.

How can I check that activity is not running or in existence any more.

Please help me if anyone know how to do this.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check here : [Proper way to know whether an Activity has been destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409747/proper-way-to-know-whether-an-activity-has-been-destroyed)

The question have your answer and as the solution provided just use the SharedPrefrence to store the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
 static boolean isActive = false;

  @Override
  public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     isActive = true;
  } 

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     isActive = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity is still in memory that's why your code is executed to finish it completed call `finish()` after starting another activity.
To check if current activity is there or not you have to override `onDestroy()` method which is called everytime when your activity is completely destroyed.
For checking activity is running or not follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771889/discovering-if-android-activity-is-running)

Answer (score 0):

just call `finish()` method when you starts a new `Activity`
like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();//this activity has been finish and the code will not execute
```

you can check if `Activity` is destroyed or not. 
override this method

```
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
Log.d("Activity name,"destroyed");
}
```