# How to go back to another Activity even if it did not create in Android?

Tags: android

Assume I have two activities.
Activity A and Activity B, while Activity A is main activity.
There is a button in Activity A that will go to Activity B.
So, Activity A -> click -> Activity B and then click back button, it will go back to Activity A.
However, there is another story that I will have a GCM notification.
When clicking the notification, it will immediately go to Activity B.
But the problem is:

1. If the application already run, when I click the notification and
   go to Activity B, and then click back button, it will correctly go
   back to Activity A.
2. If I kill the application, and click the notification and go to
   Activity B, and then click back button, it will go to the Home
   Screen. But the problem is I want it will go back to Activity A.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: This might confuse the users. Goes against the Android "Pattern" . You could provide a separate button to go to Activity A? And let the Back Press do what it does.

Comment: override onBackpressed in your Activity B and start your activity A from there then it will work in both use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override you onBackPressed method and start the activity A using an intent.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
        // Start Activity A heres
}
```

Comment: if Activity A already created, will it have some problems if I start the activity again?

Comment: You can kill Activity A when moving to Activity B to ensure that you wont have that extra Activity. Just add finish(); after startActivity().

Comment: There is another way to find out the running activities too. You can try to see if Activity A is running or not.

Comment: but the case is that I want to go back to Activity A if it exists, otherwise just create it. How to check?

Comment: There are different ways to do it as listed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446565/android-how-do-i-check-if-activity-is-running. Like using a static value, ....

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// Don't forget to remove super.onBackPressed()
startActivity(new Intent(ActivityB.this,ActivityA.class));

}
```