# repeatedly checking whether the application is in foreground or background

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to detect when the app comes from back ground to foreground every time.
I'm geting the state using the following code

```
   topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())
```

But I need to execute the code repeatedly so that I could detect every time when my app comes to foreground

Comment: you can use background service and alarmManger

Comment: By the app you mean your own build app or any other app?

Answer (score 1):

It's your app. Activity always knows if it is visible or not. So make every your activity tell someone it's state. You don't need to poll app state. [Check this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038399/how-to-check-if-activity-is-in-foreground-or-in-visible-background)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    public static String isApplicationSentToBackground(final Context context) {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
        ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
        if (topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            return "true";
        }
    }

    return "false";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Most users will not want to grant your app the permission that you need to call `getRunningTasks()`. It will look like your app is spyware. Don't do this.