# Second Activity Opens After the HOME button is pressed

Tags: android, android-activity, android-homebutton

In my application I have a SplashScreen  which is opened when the app is launched. And after 1 second the Login activity is opened. But I have an issue when the HOME button is pressed right after the app is launched. If I tap on the HOME button, only when the splash screen is visible, the app closes but after a few seconds (aprox. 2 sec) the Login activity opens even if the app is not visible anymore (it is alive only in the back stack).

Here is how I start the Login activity:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                // Show login screen
                Utility.startLoginActivity(SplashScreenActivity.this);

            }
        }, 1000);
```

And this is the startLoginActivity() method:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(activity, LoginActivity.class);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 activity.startActivity(intent);
 // Finish the calling activity
 activity.finish();
```

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add check if splash activity is visible:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            if (SplashActivity.isVisible()) {
                // Show login screen
                Utility.startLoginActivity(SplashScreenActivity.this);
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
```

SplashActivity.isVisible() method can be implemented as described here: [How to check if activity is in foreground or in visible background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038399/how-to-check-if-activity-is-in-foreground-or-in-visible-background)

Comment: Thank you very much. Your link helped me a lot. Now it seems to work fine. Thanks again :)