# Is possible to check running application currently is showing or not on Android device

Tags: android, android-activity, show-hide, foreground, background-foreground

I'm working with `Receiver` and I can detect Wifi state changes in Wifi Setting System.

But I need to know `specified application is showing or not` to do more thing,

ex. if specified application was hide in Background, do nothing, and if it was showing for user to integrate, I will do something.

People who know how to check `specified application was running is showing or not`,

Please help me,

p/s :

- I have 1 `Receiver` and 1 `Activity` (is "specified Application" as I mentioned)
- I can integrate in `onReceive` method, it means I know how to receive signal.

Thanks.

**SOLUTION**

Okay, thank you,

I know how to check.

I need stored `public static boolean` in `onPause` method, to indicate current is `invisible` state.

And when `onResume` method was called, the above boolean will be in `Visible` state.

[How to check if activity is in foreground or in visible background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038399/how-to-check-if-activity-is-in-foreground-or-in-visible-background)

Comment: current application meaning your app? okay, you can extend your application class, since you are using recievers, and create a static boolean `ishowing();` in your application class.. and check for it in onreceive

Comment: Could you please be a bit more clearer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thank you,

I know how to check.

I need to store `public static boolean` in `onPause()` method, to indicate its currently in `invisible` state.

And when `onResume` method is called, the above boolean will be in `Visible` state.

[How to check if activity is in foreground or in visible background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038399/how-to-check-if-activity-is-in-foreground-or-in-visible-background)