# GCM Notification Handling and avoiding activity open if in same activity

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on application which uses GCM service.
I'm able to send notifications with code

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Intent msgMainActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
msgMainActivity.putExtra("msg", msg);
msgMainActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,msgMainActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

//  contentIntent.
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("appName Notification")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(sndr+": "+msg)
            .setNumber(notifNo); //static id notifNo

// Set notification sound
Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(notifNo++, mBuilder.build()); // separate notifications each time
```

And receiver in main activity is like

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
super.onNewIntent(intent);
Bundle notificationData = intent.getExtras();
String notifMessage = notificationData.getString("msg");
// rest code for appending notifMessage in file.txt
}
```

When user1 sends data to another user via gcm notification, user2 received it and on select able to write to file at his device
I'm facing some problems like:
 1. When User1 sends 3-4 messages continuously, all are showed separately because of `mNotificationManager.notify(notifNo++, mBuilder.build());` , which i want to avoid and send list of all 3-4 msgs in sequence as a notification.
 2. When user2 receives message through notification and is in same activity, avoid notification and write to file/ receive in activity directly.
Note: I'm doing this for multicast push notification, hence collapse key might not allow more than 4 users/messages when any of the users is offline.
Kindly pardon if repeating and post suggesting links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out solution with some help over StackOverflow questions.
On HandleIntent, I did some changes like,

> 1. When User1 sends 3-4 messages continuously, all are showed separately because of mNotificationManager.notify(notifNo++, mBuilder.build()); , which i want to avoid and send list of all 3-4 msgs in sequence as a notification."

For this, I've removed `notifNo++` to get all messages in same notification, what I've added extra is,

- while changing `inActivity` status, I'm making String `NotifData = ""`
- On first notification, I'm sending user notification with `NOTIFICATION_ID`
- When user gets another notification, append `NotifData` with new line character. (you may comment better approach).
- Again on `onNewIntent()`, I'm making `NotifData = ""`.

> 2. When user2 receives message through notification and is in same activity, avoid notification and write to file/ receive in activity directly.

For this I've added one static boolean variable `inActivity`, which will be true only if user is currently on activity screen i.e. `onCreate(), onNewIntent(), onStart(), onPause()` and false on respective methods like `onStop()` etc. Based on this variable check, I'm deciding to call `mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());` Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038399/how-to-check-if-activity-is-in-foreground-or-in-visible-background) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper class with the following methods that tracks which activity is currently open.

```
/** A set which maintains the visible activities **/
private static final Collection<String> sVisiblePages = new HashSet<>();

/** Call this when your Page becomes visible, tracking ID is the 
unique ID for an activity (You can use class name) */
public static void markPageAsVisible(String trackingID){
    sVisiblePages.add(trackingID);
}

 /** Whether or not a page with this tracking ID is visible to the user. */
public static boolean isPageVisible(String trackingID){
    return sVisiblePages.contains(trackingID);
}

/**
 * Marks this page as hidden upon validating that it is indeed going into background
 * and not getting re-created due to an orientation change.
 * */
public static void markPageAsHidden(Activity activity, String trackingID){
    if(!activity.isChangingConfigurations()) markPageAsHidden(trackingID);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I couldn't get how is it helping and to which point you are answering..