# Single IabHelper instance for multiple Activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, in-app-billing

I am trying to implement in-app billing for my app. And I am following the [Android In-app billing tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/index.html) from Google.

In the tutorial, `IabHelper` is an instance variable of an `Activity`. To instantiate an `IabHelper`, we need to pass a `Context`, in this case the `Activity` itself.

I have several `Activty`s that need to communicate with the Google Play Store. Is it bad to create multiple `IabHelper`s for different `Activity`s?

If it is bad, how do I make one `IabHelper` available for different `Activity`s? How how do I tell the `IabHelper` that the `Context` has changed as I switch between `Activity`s?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've found next solution:
I do initialization inside Application > onCreate method:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        final IabHelper iabHelper = IabHelper.createInstance(getApplicationContext(), AppHelper.getPublicKey());
}
```

Then when you need to launch a purchase you should do:

```
public static void launchPurchase():void {
    final AppCompatActivity foregAct = sFacade.getForegroundActivity();
    final String payload = AppHelper.generateDeveloperPayload();
    final IabHelper iabHelper = IabHelper.getInstance();
    if (iabHelper != null) {
        iabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(foregAct, AppHelper.SKU_PRO, AppHelper.RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
    }
}
```

Where getForegroundActivity can be implemented in different way for example:

```
public AppCompatActivity getForegroundActivity() {
    if (MainActivity.isForeground) {
        return (AppCompatActivity) retrieveEntity(MainActivity.NAME);
    } else if (MiscActivity.isForeground) {
        return (AppCompatActivity) retrieveEntity(MiscActivity.NAME);
    } if (GameActivity.isForeground) {
        return (AppCompatActivity) retrieveEntity(GameActivity.NAME);
    }  else {
        return (AppCompatActivity) retrieveEntity(HelpActivity.NAME);
    }
}
```

Or you can choose another methods for tracking foreground activity:

[How to check if activity is in foreground or in visible background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038399/how-to-check-if-activity-is-in-foreground-or-in-visible-background)

[Android: How can I get the current foreground activity (from a service)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873659/android-how-can-i-get-the-current-foreground-activity-from-a-service)

At last, don't dispose IabHelper in any activity. And you should include handling code into each activity from which you can launch a purchase:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        final IabHelper iabHelper = IabHelper.getInstance();
        if (iabHelper != null) {
            iabHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
}
```