# Android, xamarin: Load RecyclerView when Activity is already visible

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my activtiy, I am loading a recyclerview that downloads pictures from the internet.

The only problem is, that the acitvity will only become visible when the loading of the pictures is done. I call the function from within the `OnCreate()` method. Since this made it obvious, I decided to put the function into `OnWindowFocusChanged()`, yet still the activity will only start showing when the pictures are loaded. (This is like a 1 second delay, but its a litttle too much.)

Where would I call my `InitRecView()` method to make sure it will start loading once the activity is already visible to the user?

Thanks

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038399/how-to-check-if-activity-is-in-foreground-or-in-visible-background

Comment: do not visible or invisible your activity. only visible your recycleview after loading

Answer (score 0):

You  are getting this problem because you are loading images on main thread. It may also cause skipping layouts.
**Here is the solution**: Use `Handler` or `Async` task for download images, show progress till then and once image is downloaded then notify adapter using `adapter.notifydatasetchanged()`.

note:make sure you write UI related code in  `runOnUiThread` since you cannot handle UI elements in background task.