# update recycler view while receive fcm notification

Tags: java, android, firebase, service, notifications

I want to refresh my recycler view in fragment while receive FCM notification(if specific fragment is open) else receive notification.

I have tried multiple solutions, but that didn't work.

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        String noti_body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        String noti_title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String noti_activity = data.get("activity");

        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "M_CH_ID")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.logo)
                .setContentTitle(noti_title)
                .setContentText(noti_body)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.logo))
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setAutoCancel(true); // clear notification after click

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
    fragmentNewJobs c = new fragmentNewJobs();
    if (c.getUserVisibleHint()) {//fragmentNewJobs.is_open
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("activity", noti_activity);
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
    }else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("activity", noti_activity);

        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
    }
   }
  }
}
```

> fragmentNewJobs c = new fragmentNewJobs();
>           if (c.getUserVisibleHint())

I have tried this, but it load `fragmentNewJobs.java` even I have opened any screen.

1. I want to refresh `recyclerView` in `fragmentNewJobs.java` only if `fragmentNewJobs` is open else receive notification.

   2. I want to add only new item to `recyclerView`(not load all data if possible)

Answer (score 1):

> i want to add only new item to recycler view(not load all data if
>   possible)

- You can use [BroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager) to send notification event to your existing Activity. Running Activity will add new item in List when it receive new broadcast.
- Another option to notify Activity can be [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), that is fast growing, easy implementation library for notifying between Services, Activities and Fragments.

[How to use BroadcastManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8802157/6891563)

[How to use EventBus?](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

> i want to refresh recyclerview in fragmentNewJobs.java only if
>   fragmentNewJobs is open else receive notification.

For this you can take a static boolean in Application class, and make it true on Fragment's `onResume()` and make it false on `onPause()`.

Then you can check Fragment's visibility by `ApplicationClass.isFragmentVisible()`

**Edit**

You can change `fragmentVisible` boolean inside `setUserVisibleHint()`  of `Fragment`, that will work perfectly. You will need to make initially `UserVisibleHint` false because it is true default. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12523627/6891563) for better understanding.

Comment: Broadcast works perfectly. but on pause is not called when i switch to other activity or fragment.

Comment: Fragment `onPause()` will always called when user is going to other Screen, either Activity or Fragment. Did you set logs in `onPause()` of fragment?

Comment: yes. i have override all methods like onPause, Onstop, OnDestroy etc..
I have multiple Fragments in MainActivity and in fragment i have view pager and set 3 tabs. if swipe to 3rd tab. then onPause calls but if change fragment from navigaton drawer then nothing is called.


@Override
    public void onPause() {
        is_open = false;
        Log.d( "receiversender: ", "on pause");
        super.onPause();
    }

Comment: That is not called because fragment is inside another parent fragment, so it is not destroyed. It just goes in stack.

Comment: any solution Please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Event Bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to publish message from receiver to particular fragment or activity.

And to findout if activity is visible or not have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24935799/4349332)

Or if you are using fragment you can use static variable in Application class to track fragment(Most basic use)

Comment: thanks @taman. Broadcast works perfectly. but (on pause , on stop , onDestroy etc )is not called when i switch to other activity or fragment. i am using it in fragment.

Comment: If you are using broadcast make sure to check out changes in marshmello for broadcast. (Broadcast receiver must be registered and unregistered from code not only from manifest)

Comment: yes. broadcast is working perfectly. only issue is how to unregistered when fragment state changes? or fragment is not active/visible?