# Notify user from IntentService only if my app is not active/foreground in Android

Tags: android, android-intentservice

I have an `IntentService` that is run from time to time to notify users to add something. I do not want to send notifications if the users are in my app (in one of the activity). Is there a simple way to achieve it?

One way is by having a boolean set in `MyApplication` and setting it true in `onStart`/`onStop` or `onResume`/`onPause`. Is this the right way?

Comment: I don't know if it's the right way, but it's logical and the way that I use and works.

Answer (score 0):

You could make all of your activities subclass a custom activity that has a static variable that keeps track of wether or not an activity is on screen.

Like: [Android: how do I check if activity is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446565/android-how-do-i-check-if-activity-is-running)

However, I would use an int instead of a boolean, just incase there is some kind of race condition between an onResume and an onPause from one activity to the next.