# How to find whether App is running or not and if App is running then how to find which activity is in front

Tags: android, android-activity, push-notification, background-foreground

I have a very hard time to finding real solution.I searched a lot but I cant find any good solution for my problem.

I want to perform some action when user click on notification.So I have to check whether application in background or foreground. If it is in foreground then which activity is running ? There must be simple way to find this.

Please Guide me on this.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "So I have to check whether application in background or foreground" -- why?

Comment: @CommonsWare : Because If application is in background then show notification otherwise show alert.So..

Answer (score 1):

You should listen in two places of your application:

- In your activity to show the alert.
- In your service to show the notification check if activity is running using one of following solutions.

You have severals answers there summarizing the solutions:

[Android: how do I check if activity is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446565/android-how-do-i-check-if-activity-is-running)

[Checking if an Android application is running in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/android-is-application-running-in-background/5862048#5862048)

Answer (score 1):

> Because If application is in background then show notification otherwise show alert.

Then *you do not care* "whether application in background or foreground" or "If it is in foreground then which activity is running".

You simply care that, when the event occurs, either the foreground UI handles it (if there is a foreground UI), or else you show a `Notification`.

One approach is to use an ordered broadcast, as [I blogged about](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html) a couple of years ago. Here is a sample app that demonstrates this. Basically, the service(?) sends an ordered broadcast. The UI has a high-priority receiver for that broadcast when it is in the foreground, and it aborts the broadcast and consume the event. You also have a low-priority receiver, one that will only get control if the UI did not consume the event, that will display the `Notification`.

Comment: Nice solution, I keep it for next time.