# How to check if the activity is open

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

I would like to somehow check if the activity is open. I have got activity1.java and activity2.java. If the user will open activity 1, textview will be green else textview will be blue(I know how to change background dynamically). I want to do it this way!

```
If (activity1 is open) {
    tv.setBackgroundColor(COLOR.GREEN);
} else if(activity2 is open) {
    tv.setBackgroundColor(COLOR.BLUE);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: how do I check if activity is running?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446565/android-how-do-i-check-if-activity-is-running)

Comment: Here is the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446565/android-how-do-i-check-if-activity-is-running. You can have static members or try to get from Activity.class compared with  getCanonicalName() value. All is displayed here in several examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just make a string variable in any activity lets say i make it on activity3 like

```
public static String activity_name=null;
```

on activity1 put a value like

```
activity3.activity_name = first;
```

on activity2 put a value like

```
activity3.activity_name = second;
```

now just check

```
if (activity3.activity_name.equals("first") && !activity3.activity_name.equals(null))
{
    tv.setBackgroundColor(COLOR.GREEN);
}
    else if(activity3.activity_name.equals("second") && !activity3.activity_name.equals(null))
{
    tv.setBackgroundColor(COLOR.BLUE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a global variable in your `Activity`, for example `boolean isVisible`. Then in your `onResume()` you set

```
isVisible = true
```

and in the `onPause()` method

```
isVisible = false
```