# Close activity from service

Tags: android, android-activity, service, activity-finish

How to close an `Activity` from a service. Here's my code in service

```
public void run() {             
    Date dt = new Date();
    int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
    if (minutes % 2 == 0) {
        stopThread();
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(this, show_act.class); 
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(i);    
    }
    else{ 
       //what must i do,. How to close show_act activities from service     
    }
}
```

Please help me solve this  . .

Answer (score 2):

In your activity's `onResume` function, register a broadcast receiver that will call the activity's `finish()` method.

In your service, when you want to close the activity, simply send the broadcast. If the activity is currently shown, the broadcast receiver will call its `finish()` method.

Comment: check if this is helpful..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446565/android-how-do-i-check-if-activity-is-running

Comment: Your broadcast receiver being registered in onResume, so you can be sure that if the broadcast is received then your activity is visible.

Comment: i already try all , but still not working. Can you write there's code?

Comment: No, sorry, you'll have to try and do that yourself, my solution should be working. Debug your code to know why. If you want, you can update your question with your current code.