# Set alarm when activity is destroyed

Tags: android, android-activity, alarmmanager

I am trying to set an alarm when activity is destroyed. But it is not working. If I set an alarm when activity is stopped, it is working. But for the destroying method, it is not working. I don't know if I am missing something or what ? If it is possible,how can I set an alarm when activity is destroyed?

Following is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {


        databaseHandler.updatePreference(Keys.Pref.APP_CRASH_STATUS, "TRUE");
        setAlarmToOpenApp();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

private void setAlarmToOpenApp(){
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(ActivityDisplay.this, AppCrashReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ActivityDisplay.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval = 10000;

        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000, pendingIntent);
        Display.log(TAG, "Alarm is set to  Broadcast app crash");
    }
```

Comment: Hmm. Maybe this would be better to implement in a [Service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html?hl=id), as `onDestroy` is possible to not get called. Also, your Activity is destroyed and therefor not available (null).

Comment: @Amylinn Is it possible send broadcast when my app is being destroyed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Check if activity is destroyed by a system from service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294812/android-check-if-activity-is-destroyed-by-a-system-from-service)

Comment: @Amylinn Yes we can check activity status by that method. But I was trying to set alarm.

Comment: It's not only about the state. Service has it's own context, you could use that instead?

Comment: @Amylinn I will try to implement using service.